# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED while accessing mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js and trying to learn it.

I have installed node-mysql NPM module.
Here i have listed my code to access mysql :

```
// Include http module, 
var http = require('http'), 
// And mysql module you've just installed. 
   mysql = require("mysql"); 

// Create the connection. 
// Data is default to new mysql installation and should be changed according to your configuration. 
var connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
   user: "root", 
   password: "", 
   database: "astitvabmt",
   host: '127.0.0.1',
   port: '3306',
   _socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
}); 

// Create the http server. 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   // Attach listener on end event. 

      // Query the database. 
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM tbluser;',function(err, results, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("sachin : " + results);
                var output = '<html><head></head><body><h1>Latest Posts</h1><ul><table border=1><tr>';
                for (var index in fields) {
                    output += '<td>' + fields[index].name + '</td>';
                }
                output += '</tr>';
                for (var index in results) {
                    output += '<tr><td>' + results[index].Recipe + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + results[index].Amount + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + results[index].Unit + '</td>';
                    output += '<td>' + results[index].Ingredient + '</td></tr>';
                }
                output += '</ul></body></html>';
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.end(output);
            });                       

// Listen on the 8080 port. 
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server mysqlJS running at 8080');
```

But i am getting error as :

```
sachin@ubuntu:/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp$ node mysql.js
Server mysqlJS running at 8080

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Handshake.Sequence (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
    at new Handshake (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:9:12)
    at Protocol.handshake (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:50)
    at Connection.connect (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:72:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:182:10)
    at Connection.query (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:8)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/mysql.js:22:18)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
```

I don't have skip-networking option in my mysql config.

**I have installed XAMPP in my PC.Previously i use 3306 port for mysql connection using apache.**

Comment: Do you have a MySQL server running on that port?

Comment: I have installed XAMPP in my PC.Previously i use 3306 port for mysql connection using apache.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `socketPath` parameter instead of `_socket`.

As noted here https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#connection-options

Comment: THIS! This fixed it for me, absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying both a hostname/port (`localhost` / `3306`) and a socket path (`/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock`) for MySQL doesn't make sense - it can only use one of those at a time. Pick whichever one is appropriate for your installation.

Comment: No,this is not solution i am not able to get access of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" socket error generally == firewall blocking mySQL port

The port in question is usually 3306.  Here are instructions for a Windows server:

http://www.activeservers.com/page3610203.aspx

And here are instructions for a Linux server:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html

Q: Are you trying to connect to mySQL on the same server (e.g. Apache co-located on the same host with MySQL), or are you trying to connect to mySQL from a different, remote host?

Comment: I have installed XAMPP in my PC.Previously i use 3306 port for mysql connection using apache.

Comment: I have used http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html but still problem is not solved.

Comment: OK: you've clarified 1) you're running on Windows, 2) your client is co-located on the same host with mySql, and 3) the same configuration works on the same PC with Apache + mySQL.  Correct?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Specify ONLY user, password, database and host in your "createConnection()", 2) Specify "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1".

Comment: I failed to start mysql on my PC.I have started it now and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAMP the default port it's 8889, it worked for me.